# Chrome/Firefox add-on or bookmarklet that retrieves external comments for a given article URL

Tags: web-browser

Is there any Chrome or Firefox extension or just a bookmarklet that retrieves comments from a hand-picked list of community websites* for a given URL?

I would like, when reading an article (or any URL, it could be the homepage or a YouTube page) to be able to quickly access the related discussions from other websites so I can get some context - other people's findings/conclusions.

Ideally listed in a sidebar, worst case just the links to the particular pages where the comments happen.

* Say, Reddit, Hacker News etc.

So, for the example, NY Times' *Starbucks to Provide Free College Education to Thousands of Workers* would gather the comments from or just point to http://redd.it/289v96, https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7896833 and maybe other related comment threads

Answer (score 2):

Check out this add-on for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/similarsites/) *or* [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/similar-sites/necpbmbhhdiplmfhmjicabdeighkndkn?hl=en-US)! I just did a few minutes of searching and believe it's exactly what you're looking for. After you install the add-on you (and restart your browser), you'll see a new button in your toolbar. Click it when you're on a page where your article is and it will show you similar pages. You can also click on the 'get more results' button at the bottom and it will break them down into four categories:

1. SimilarSites
2. Similar By Visit
3. Similar By Searches
4. Similar By Topics

I really hope this helps and works well for you!

Comment: Could you make your (already good) answer self-containing by explicitely naming the add-on, so that your answer stays relevant in case of dead link?

Comment: No problem, I usually do but was sleeping on that one. It's actually the first item in the list above, SimilarSites.

Comment: Sorry, but this gets nowhere near answering my question.

Comment: It does not show you the comments related to the article your current viewing, but it will take you to pages related to related pages where you can view the comments and where the discussions are taking place. It's one extra step you have to take but a better solution than having nothing and is (from what I gathered from your question) about as close of solution you're going to find. There aren't nearly as many browser add-ons as there are Android apps (for instance) and sometimes you just have to customize the currently available options to best fit your needs, as I often end up doing.

Comment: If someone else finds and suggests a better add-on, fantastic, but until then this add-on should help you (at least a little) find similar comments and discussions about the article you're currently viewing.